# Adobe AS3 About Menu

Tags: android, adobe, action

I want to create an about menu with Adobe AS3

My app is done i just want a little window or android menu to pop up when i press the android device menu key.

could i adjust a symbols opacity by using the event listeners?

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, handleKeyUp);

Adjust a symbols parameters when key is lifted to reveal something hidden.